# How much storage to represent sparse matrix

Tags: memory, matrix, data-structures, storage, bit

I don`t know how to solve this problem in *Fundamentals of data structure in C* ed.2nd ch2.5

On a computer with w bits per word, how much storage is needed to represent a sparse matrix, A, with t nonzero terms?

I think the answer is 3*w*t because in sparse matrix we just store row, col and values,
so 3 times w*t but someone says answer is w<sup>2</sup> + t.... I don't understand what they mean.

Answer (score 0):

In the most common “general purpose” sparse matrix formats (CSR and CSC), for a matrix with *t* nonzeros, there are two integer arrays, of lengths *t+1* and *t*, and one array of floating-point numbers of length *t*. In practice, the size in bytes will depend on the sizes of the integer and floating-point representations. In a theoretical machine with one uniform word size for everything, the size would be *3t+1* words.

I fail to see how *w^2+t* could be correct or even related.